# Django: no such table: users_company

Tags: django, migration

i was trying to create a user's company profile but i got the following error:

```
OperationalError at /admin/users/company/
Exception Value:    
no such table: users_company
```

I think theres something wrong in my user' model.py because when i try to make migrations myapp> it shows
`No changes detected in app`

model.py:

```py
class Company(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    about = models.TextField(gettext_lazy('about'), max_length=500, blank=True)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    contact=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Company'
```

Does anyone can help me with this? I am new to django, lmk if you need any other information. Thanks !

Comment: Your current model.py is ok, but if the migrations cause problem it's because of _previous_ versions of models.py, you could delete the database and all the migrations (if your db is empty or you don't care about the data) or try to see which migration causes problem.

Comment: Your __str__ function however is a bit strange, you use self.user but user is not declared. Maybe add a "user = ForeignKey(User)" in your class Company ?

Comment: There is no ForeignKey from User in your model, just like @RobertVandenEynde said, add a "user = ForeignKey(User)" in your current model, makemigrations and migrate.

Comment: @RobertVandenEynde I deleted database and migrations but it still the same